# Count number of dataframe entries with certain value using python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my pandas Dataframe i want to access the `status` column and count the number of times the value `Fail` appears. I am trying to implement a `groupby` method in order to see the number of fails but i am getting a weird output in the picture:

```
total = df.groupby("status").sum()
```

[image: h]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [38]: df = pd.DataFrame(["Fail","OK"] * 9, columns=["status"])

In [39]: df["status"].value_counts()
Out[39]:
OK      9
Fail    9
Name: status, dtype: int64
```

Use `value_counts()` to get the count of occurrence

Comment: The above was just an example. The main command to use is `value_counts()` on your column